# convert to lower of nearest 1000 in java

Tags: java

convert to lower of nearest 1000 in java

I want to convert to lower 1000 example

4300 should be 4000

4900 should be 4000

10050 should be 10000

how can we do this using java

sorry for the bad english

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [ask].

Comment: Just divide and again multiply by 1000. for example 4300/1000 * 1000=4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int value = …
int nearestThousand = value / 1_000 * 1_000;
```